# Android bluetooth scan of already paired

Tags: android, bluetooth

I'm making an Android application that scan all device in the room and connect/pair to the device automatically or not, depending on the name prefix.

I tried some examples and the scan result return only unpaired devices. So I need that the result of the scan return also already paired devices. Is it possible on Android ? (I already done this on windows)

Comment: How is it possible to pair automatically? Could you give me a sample code?

Comment: This is what I wanted to do, because I already did it on PC. But in fact, it seem very hard and I don't have this feature in my software.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You need to get the local bluetooth adapter

```
Adapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
```

get paired devices into a private set Bluetooth device

```
devicepair = Adapter.getBondedDevices();
```

And then from that point it should be a simple for loop to add device pair to a list view that shows your bluetooth devices

```
 for(BluetoothDevice : devicepair)
//your array name or whatever inside the for loop 
listviewarray.add(devicepair.getName());
```

Comment: But contrary to scanning, you don't get the UUIDs of offered services. So you can not limit your selection to the devices that offer the one service your app needs.